# Using .net interop assembly from PowerBuilder IDE

Tags: com-interop, powerbuilder

I have created a .net assembly and am able to call and use the assembly at will from outside the PowerBuilder 12.1 IDE within my applications distribution (regasm).
However while I develop inside the IDE the assembly is not visible.  How can I access the assembly from within the IDE so I can work with the assembly and my code together?

Comment: See these articles: http://brucearmstrong.ulitzer.com/node/258395
   
http://brucearmstrong.ulitzer.com/node/397016

Comment: Hi, I have done some further digging.  apparently to make the DLL work inside the PowerBuilder IDE is create a manifest file for the PowerBuilder IDE exe.  The assembly itelf needs to be in the same folder as the PowerBuilder IDE exe.  I do not know how to create the manifest file.  Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does anyone have experience in adding manifest to PB120.exe to reference an interop .net DLL?

Comment: I remember doing something like that a few years ago at another job, but I don't have access to the files anymore. I seem to remember that newer versions of PowerBuilder already came with a manifest so I wasn't able to use it. (I could be wrong about that.) I think I ended up just registering the dll as a COM component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your .Net component is COM visible.  Even then, the methods on the assembly will only be 'visible' in the PB IDE if they are given a DispID and such in .Net.

Comment: Won't he also have to register the COM objects on his system? (Or use registry-less COM)

Comment: Hi thanks for responses all. So my PB runtime works just fine. It's COM visible. The only issue is running inside powerbuilder's ID.

Comment: Yes, you do need to register the DLL on the system for PB to communicate with it.